# 12.04 LTS How to get Compose Key to work?

Tags: language-support, input-language

**12.04 LTS**

I'm trying to get the Portuguese (Brazil) keyboard layout to work with accents and punctuation. I tried different keys for my Compose Key (Right Ctrl, Right Alt, Left Win, etc...), but none are working. I can't figure out why. Thanks.

Comment: Check if you're typing the keys in the right order, in my case I have to do it in the following order: Compose->accent to add-> letter to add the accent to. As an exmample LeftAlt+Apostrophe+e=é. I've found that sometimes you have to try it out in different combinations as not all systems are the same.

Comment: @Oyibo I tried every possible combination and several different possible composition key choices, but it doesn't work. Am I missing something more basic? Do I have to download a Portuguese language file?

Comment: I'm not aware of needing any language file from past experience, I only have english and it works fine. Though maybe check that you have the "Use the same layout for all windows" ticked, maybe your keyboard switches to another layout for certain windows. If that doesn't help I'm not of much help I'm afraid :(